# How to multiply two matrix in matlab without loop

Tags: matlab

Given two 100x3 matrix A and B. How do I multiple them in Matlab without loop such that the output matrix is (sorry for the bad format).

`a11*b11  a12*b12  a13*b13
 a21*b21  a22*b22  a23*b23
 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we say output matrix is C, then: `C = A.*B`

Comment: Thank you for the help. How do I calculate a11*b11 +a12*b12 +a13*b13 ?

Comment: If that answers your first question, please accept the answer :)  If you'd like to sum the columns in a new 100x1 matrix D, then try `D = sum(C,2)`

Answer (score 1):

use a dot for element wise multiplication `A.*B`